# Drupal 7 - More link in view not showing

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-7

The 'more link' is not shown in a block, while my settings are as shown here:

[image: My views block]

I do have more than 2 items. Do you have an idea what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It's a block. So the read more button doesn't know where it should be linked to.
To fixed this you have to enter url of the target page into Advance -> link display at the right side.

[image: Click "link display"]
[image: Enter url]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a page display for your View?  If not, then the *more* link won't have anywhere to go and therefore is not displayed.  Try creating a Page display for your view.

Comment: @nmc That's the problem what I got, what if you got a Page display for your view? But still doesn't redirect you to the article?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Content: Path field above your Content:body field, and exclude the Content: Path field from display.

Then, in your Content: body field, select Rewrite Results, and then Trim this field to a maximum length.

Next, set the More Link Text to "Read More"

Finally, under the More Link Path, add in [path] which is found under the Regular Expressions section.

Click save, and for any body content longer than the maximum length, there will be a read more link inline which links to your article.